# jquery scroll animation not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm implementing infinity scrolling with jquery and here all list item is rendering data from database. everything is working well but my scroller not scrolling with animation its looks like its just jumping how could i make it animate not jumping!... please

[Jquery]

```
var item_width = $('.scroller li').outerWidth();
var left_value = item_width * (-1);
$('.scroller li:first').before($('.scroller li:last'));
$('.scroller').css({'left' : left_value});

$('#prev').click(function() {
    var left_indent = parseInt($('.scroller').css('left')) - item_width;
    $('.scroller').animate({'left' : '-='+left_indent}, 400, function(){
        $('.scroller li:first').before($('.scroller li:last'));
        $('.scroller').css({'left' : left_value});
    });
    return false;
});

$('#next').click(function() {
    var left_indent = parseInt($('.scroller').css('left')) - item_width;
    $('.scroller').animate({'left' : '+='+left_indent}, 400, function () {
        $('.scroller li:last').after($('.scroller li:first'));
        $('.scroller').css({'left' : left_value});
    });
    return false;
});
```

[Style]

```
*{margin: 0;padding: 0;list-style: none;}
.scroller{height:70px;overflow:hidden;}
.scroller li{float:left;display:inline-block;position:relative;border-bottom:1px solid #e8eef4;border-top:1px solid #e8eef4;border-right:1px solid #ddd;height:70px;width:25%;cursor:pointer;
    background-image: -moz-radial-gradient(top, #fff, #ddd);}
.scroller li:nth-child(4),.scroller li:nth-of-type(4){border-right:0}
.scroller li a{display:block;margin-top:8%;height:90%;font-size:x-small;text-align:center;}
.scroller .active,.scroller li:hover{background-image:-moz-radial-gradient(top, #ddd, #fff)}
.scroller .active:before{content:'';height:0;position:absolute;top:-1px;width:0;left:42%;border: 10px solid transparent;border-top-color:#fff;z-index:100}
.scroller li a img{border:1px solid #ccc;width:80%;height:40%}
```

[Html]

```
<div>
   <ul class="scroller">
      <li class="item">01</li>
      <li class="item">02</li>
      <li class="item">03</li>
      <li class="item">04</li>
      <li class="item">05</li>
      <li class="item">06</li>
      <li class="item">07</li>
      <li class="item">08</li>
      <li class="item">09</li>
      <li class="item">10</li>
   </ul>
   <p class="tar"><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="prev">&lsaquo;</a><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="next">&rsaquo;</a></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use lucid.js, they did a great job and i think it can save your time.
They have a nice API which let you choose what elements you want to scroll or even the whole page.

Please let me know if it helps you.

here is the link for documentations and demos : http://ataredo.com/morphology/lucidscroll/

Comment: It's size is 4.78KB, which will loss my page load time. and i don't want use any plugin! is there any solution?